# Propagation Delay in OPNET Modeler 14.5

Tags: networking, delay, propagation

I have implemented a simple scenario in OPNET modeler 14.5.but having trouble calculating the propagation delay of my 10Base-T links.

I know: propagation delay = link length/propagation speed of the link
but don't know the propagation speed of these 10Base-T Ethernets.

Could anyone help me where to find this propagation speed in opnet?

Comment: If you have solved this already, please share your solution. Thank you.

Comment: I used: 1/Propagation Speed=5 (nanosec/m) for Optical fiber.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the speed of light (3.xxE8 m/s) or one of attribute of link model is the Speed of Light.